# NHibernate OnConnected

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have .NET application with Oracle Database and NHibernate.
I need to handle some "Connected" event which raised before NHibernate executed first DbCommand with currently used OracleConnection. This is due to the necessity of primary context initialization. I need to be sure that before executing any command context was initialized.
Is there such a possibility in NHibernate?

P.S. I can not use Oracle ON LOGON TRIGGER for this purpose

UPD. The solution is:

```
public class CustomConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
    {
        public override System.Data.IDbConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var conn = (OracleConnection)base.GetConnection();
            //init context
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [DriverConnectionProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21893267/12752). Normally this is used to dynamically change the connection but it seems like a good fit for your scenario. Since it's responsible for creating and opening the connection, you are guaranteed that no operations have occurred before it executes.